# getView fragment from activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to get the view created in onCreateView () (Fragment) to modify components through findviewbyId but always returns null

eg

this is onCreateView in my fragment

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, container, false);


        return view;
    }
```

and from my activity call fragment and add eg.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                Fragment newFragment = new myFragment();

                ft.replace(main_container.getId(), newFragment).commit();


/*and i need modify the text button with setText() of View create in my fragment 
eg*/
View  myViewFragment = newFragment.getView();

Button b = (Button) myViewFragment.findViewById(R.id.mybuttoninfragment);

b.setText("Hello World");
```

but always returns null, how do I fix this?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because ft.replace(main_container.getId(), newFragment).commit(); just *request an initiation* of the fragment transaction, but it will only actually be done (and thus onCreateView() be invoked) the next time the main thread have spare CPU cycles.

So, you'll have to wait calling

```
View  myViewFragment = newFragment.getView();
```

etc to at a later time (in an onClick() method for example)